# Stone’s Theorem and Time Ordered Exponentials

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, mathematical-physics, time-evolution, unitarity

The time evolution operator of quantum mechanics seems (at least to me) to form a strongly continuous, one parameter group of unitary operators. Hence, by Stone’s theorem, we should have that $U(t) = \exp(it\hat{h})$ for some self-adjoint operator $\hat{h}$. But, outside of the Heisenberg picture, we have in general that $U(t) = T\exp\left(\int_{t_0}^{t}\hat{H}(t’)\,dt’\right)$ which is not of the simple form guaranteed by Stone’s theorem. Does this mean that there is a simpler (though possibly less physical) realization of $U(t)$ lying around, or that one of the hypotheses of Stone’s theorem was violated (or something else)?

Comment: There should be a treatment of the general time evolution somewhere in the four volumes of Reed & Simon.

Answer (score 4):

The conditions needed for Stone's theorem require that
$$U(t,t') = U(t-t',0)$$
for any $t,t'$. This is certainly not satisfied by a general time-dependent Hamiltonian $H(t)$. (Consider e.g. turning on a potential at time $t = 0$, then $U(s+\delta s,s)$ will depend on whether $s < 0$ or $s>0$.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nitpick (maybe the crucial one?): $U(t)$ is not a [$C_0$ semigroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0-semigroup) because it fails the second condition:

2. $\forall t,r\ U(t+r)=U(t)\,U(r)$

since the choice of $t_0$ from which we evolve the system affects the second product differently than the first: The first operator evolves the system to time $t_0+t+r$ whereas the second (in the best case scenario, time invariant Hamiltonian) evolves the system to $t_0+r+(t_0-t)$, and in the worst case scenario the operation is not physically meaningful since we are trying to evolve the system at time $t_0+r$ using a Hamiltonian that is retarded (starts from time $t_0$).

(Note: I have little-to-none knowledge on operator theory, so things above might not even make sense. I welcome any improvements.)